# Extension VS code copilot

Tags: github-copilot

I have installed the latest version of Copilot, but I am receiving messages indicating that my editor's Copilot extension (version 'copilot/1.31.6194') is out of date and that I need to install a newer version to access the service. I have already tried uninstalling and reinstalling both the extension and VS Code itself, but the issue persists. Any ideas on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: not a question for stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

On my MacOS, I had VS Code installed. To download it, I had to move it to the applications folder and then update Visual Studio again